# Как сделать непрямоугольное окно?

Tags: c, windows, интерфейс

Я видел приложения, окна которых имеют какую-то фантастическую форму.

Вопрос: как сделать окно произвольной формы в Windows 7 на Си?

Comment: Я так понимаю что окно фактически всегда будет прямоугольным, но можно к примеру, сделать его прозрачным, а фон не прозрачным, при  этом фон может быть любой формы, если наложить на него произвольный рисунок.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я знаю такие способы:

**С помощью функции`SetWindowRgn`**

- Простой способ
- Окно будет "прозрачным" для событий мыши, т.е. не будет реагировать на нажатия мыши в прозрачных областях
- Не поддерживает альфа блендинг (края будут рваные)

**С помощью расширенного стиля `WS_EX_LAYERED`**

- Поддерживает попиксельный альфа-блендинг или хромакей
- Более сложен в использовании, если нужен попиксельный альфа-блендинг

При использовании `WS_EX_LAYERED`, прозрачные пиксели (хромакей) можно устанавливать так:

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hWnd, RGB(R,G,B), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Естественно, по `WM_PAINT` вы должны заливать прозрачные области тем же цветом.

Если вам нужен попиксельный альфа-блендинг, окно нужно отрисовывать не по `WM_PAINT`, а особым методом с использованием функции `UpdateLayeredWindow` ([пример](http://duckmaestro.com/2010/06/06/per-pixel-alpha-blending-in-win32-desktop-applications/)). Но есть и подводные камни - по RDP окно отображаться не будет. В этом случае нужно делать fallback на хрома-кей.